# Unable to successfully build the rocker/r-apt image NO GPG KEY found

Tags: r, ubuntu, debian, apt-get

I am attempting to utilize the rocker/r-apt image which enables R binary installs.
My 72 Minute Docker Build using the r-base image could use some help...

My file looks like this.

```
FROM container.registry/rocker/r-apt:bionic
RUN apt-get update
```

Couple of notes. My company uses an internal registry, so i've downloaded the image from
https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/r-apt
and pushed it to my local container registry.

When I try and build the Docker container it gives me this error.
**UPDATE - Full Error message**

```
/deb.debian.org/debian testing InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 04EE7237B7D453EC NO_PUBKEY 648ACFD622F3D138
```

I can post a more detailed error message when the internet on my other computer returns.

I realize now that bionic is the Ubuntu distro.  r-base uses a debian base from what I can tell.

My big question..what am I doing wrong to get this rocker/r-apt image to run correctly and still allow me to use apt-get to install a number of things, include the cran-r packages that its supposed to enable.

I am following this post by datawookie.
https://datawookie.netlify.app/blog/2019/01/docker-images-for-r-r-base-versus-r-apt/

**UPDATE**
My new big question... should i be pointing at `deb.debian.org/debian` for apt-get?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `rocker/r-ubuntu` instead of `rocker/r-apt` (which predates it).  I am the man behind the curtain for both.

Within Rocker we have containers based on Debian, and containers based on Ubuntu, and containers based on Debian now that will likely be based on Ubuntu in the future. In short, "it's complicated" but that is in part ... because we have so darn many containers already.

The source for background information is still [our R Journal paper](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2017/RJ-2017-065/index.html) (shortcut to [pdf](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2017/RJ-2017-065/RJ-2017-065.pdf)).

Comment: Thanks for responding!   I read most of the white paper and it states all rocker images are based on Debian, yet when i look at source i see ubuntu? I know the two are closely related, but are they compatible?  I missed the connection since the white paper doesn't touch on whats going on there.

Also when you state _build on_ r-base, which we currently use btw, what does that mean?  Source doesn't have a `FROM r-base` which is what I typically mean from that terminology. @dirk eddelbuettel.

Thanks again, I'm an MLE just trying to improve this guys timeseries. lol.

Comment: The Dockerfiles are all public and on GitHub and some may be newer than the published paper revision.  But we're not hiding anything...  I am a bit short on time right now debugging something else, sorry.

Comment: But the long and the short of it is that the 2019 blog post you quote is wrong / outdated. Use `rocker/r-ubuntu`.  I _made it_ to make access of these PPAs and their 4000+ `r-cran-*` binary packages easier.

Comment: copy that @Dirk Eddelbuettel

Comment: **Update on this**. I was able to download the r-ubuntu, exec into it and things appear as normal.
My org uses a nexus repo, proxy, so in order to actually test the apt-get R binary piece I need to work thru those details.  Pretty involved setup, I've made it to acquiring the Michael Rutter ppa, which requires some hoops.

Answer (score 0):

Success!!!  So the R-Ubuntu 20.04 appears to be working like a charm.
My outcome of decreasing the build time of my R application has worked.

**72 Minutes is now 4 Minutes**

This is important because our applications run in CI/CD pipelines and so a 72 minute build is extremely annoying. Not to mention consumes lots of resources to compile code.

It looks like all my issues were related to my organizations Nexus Repository.
Once we downloaded the R-Ubuntu, we had to rebuild it from the GIT Repo to utilize our internal Ubuntu Image.  That fixed 1 problem.

Then I had to import the Michael Rutter Repo as a source and update that to utilize the internal repository.

The one issue that might not be apparent is that the DockerFile has to have the apt-get update and installs in the correct order.  I do not recall if the source image had all this, but I'll post the order here.

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg2 \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        dialog \
        software-properties-common \
        ed \
        less \
        locales \
        vim-tiny \
        wget \
        ca-certificates
```

So once all that was setup it worked like magic.